# How can I install different versions of MySQL on Windows 10?

Tags: mysql, windows-installer, multiple-versions

I would like to install different MySQL versions on Windows. I have a MySQL 5.5 running, and I want to install a MySQL 5.7 to debug compatibility issues of a program I am working on. Both installations should stay side at a side, may have their own databases (it’s OK to start with an empty 5.7) and I am happy to run or stop the one or other from the *Services* control panel manually. The nowadays *MySQL installer - community* wants to upgrade my existing installation and, unlike [explained in this article](http://www.geeksengine.com/article/install-two-mysql.html), does not offer another option to install the versions side to side. All I found was a [rant](https://blog.webyog.com/mysql-windows-installer-mess/) confirming my problem, but no real solution. If it requires me to install it manually, I need detailed instructions. In my case, default setup (default port) is sufficient, because I don’t need to run both instances the same time.

Answer (score 9):

This is not so obvious but using the "MySQL installer", you need to run it, then click on "Cancel" and a new window will appear, letting you install new elements. You can then select the version(s) of MySQL that you want to add to your system.

You don't need it but if people want to run several instances at the same time, they need to choose a different port for each installation.

Comment: This is really mysterious... but it worked! Thanks @robin850, you saved my day!

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer, saved me lot of trouble.

Answer (score 4):

Why not simply use a virtual machines to install your different MySQL version ?

Like that you will be sure to have no compatibilty issues between them and you can start/stop vms as you like.

Otherwise, I did find that : https://www.codementor.io/arpitbhayani/setup-multiple-mysql-servers-with-different-versions-docker-du107solq but can't confirm it's working.

Answer (score 1):

Use Dockerized mysql and you can run as many mysql versions you want on different ports.